# Chicxulub Asteroid Remains?

Tags: geology, natural-disasters, impacts

Do scientists know if the Chicxulub asteroid disintegrated completely upon impact or if any (large or small) chunks of the asteroid remained intact? If it is possible that a significant fragment of the asteroid survived could it have been preserved until today somehow (i.e. can it be found)?

Comment: Well...the iridium layer found around the earth that marks the K-T boundary could certainly be considered remains of the bolide that created the Chicxulub crater.

Answer (score 3):

There are micro-tectites galore, strewn over thousands of square kilometres. But remains of the actual bolide? Hard to say, because the impact crater is now buried under 600 metres of sediment. Earlier this year the joint IODP-ICDP drilling program drilled to a depth of 1300 metres. As far as I know, their findings are not published yet.

Comment: Looking forward to see the results of the drilling project. Should be interesting,

Answer (score -2):

https://products.kitsapsun.com/archive/1998/11-19/0016_extinction__piece_of_dinosaur-kil.html
Here you go. Its amazing to see what happened to Earth, at the end of the Mesazoic.

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanation to this answer? We prefer not to rely on links that could go dead. Nice find though!